# Create new table entry with user_id POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, input

Ruby on Rails 3

I have a form commiting a user_id. I am trying to get the POST to create a new Certificate entry with the user_id, as well as making the :attend attribute "yes".

The post sent is:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xYUdeMjkxa1b0AhNTKJi9sDbSPo9MbwMMVPrV7cgpyo=", "certificate"=>[{"user_id"=>"1"}], "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

This is my edit:

```
<%= form_for(@trained) do |f| %>
  <%= select_tag "certificate[][user_id]", options_for_select(@current_users.collect{|x| [x.name, x.id]}), {:multiple => :multiple} %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

This is my model:

```
class Certificate < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :attend, :pass, :user_id

  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

This is my controller for the edit()

```
def edit
@trained = Certificate.new(params[:user_id])
end
```

This is my certificates_controller for create()

```
def create
  @trained = params[:certificate][:user_id] 
  params[:certificate][:attend] = "no"
  params[:certificate][:pass] = "no"
end
```

I have been trying different create() methods but am at a loss. How do I get the POST to create a new certificate with the user_id? I need to make the sumbit button into two buttons, one for add and one for remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why have you select_tag "certificate[][user_id]" remove that extra [] from there

```
select_tag "certificate[user_id]"
```

also in controller

```
@trained = Certificate.new(params[:certificate])
params[:certificate][:attend] = "no"
params[:certificate][:pass] = "no"
@trained.save
```

Comment: Do you know why I get this error: Template is missing

Missing template certificates/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/opt/RoR/reseller_connect/app/views"

Comment: yes when your create action is executed it will then look for file named with create in the views/ folder for that controller so it can return a response to user. so if you want to render any other file you can use render 'file_name' or if you want to redirect user to some other action than you can use redirect_to tag :)